# difference between 'where' null and 'on' in a left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

Could someone explain to me why

```
select "talent".* from "talent" 
left join "push" on "push"."talentId" = "talent"."id" 
where ("push"."offerId" = '403' or "push"."offerId" is null)
```

yields less results than

```
select "talent".* from "talent" 
left join "push" on "push"."talentId" = "talent"."id" and "push"."offerId" in ('403')
```

The way I see it, it should boil down to the same result, but it doesn’t, and I’m not sure what I miss to get it.

first one does not contain rows that have no entry in the `push` table.

I’d expect them to be caught by the `or "push"."offerId" is null`.

EDIT:
here is an example:
talent table

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Bob  |
|  3 | Jack |
+----+------+
```

push table

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | talentId | offerId |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |     403 |
|  2 |        1 |      42 |
|  3 |        2 |     123 |
|  3 |        2 |     456 |
+----+----------+---------+
```

With this data, the query with the `where` clause returns only

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | offerId |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | John | 403     |
+----+------+---------+
```

while the one with the `on` condition returns all wanted rows

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | offerId |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | John | 403     |
|  2 | Bob  | null    |
|  3 | Jack | null    |
+----+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is when there is a match but on another row.  This is best shown with a small example.

Consider:

t1:

```
x      y
1      abc
1      def
2      xyz
```

t2:

```
x      y
1      def
```

Then the `left join` version returns all three rows in `t1`:

```
select *
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.x = t2.x and t1.y = t2.y;
```

The filtering in the `where` clause version:

```
select *
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.x = t2.x
where t2.y = 'abc' or t2.y is null;
```

returns only one rows.  The row that is returned is `1`/`abc`.  `x = 2` matches in `t2`.  So, `t2.y` is not `null`.  And it is not `'abc'` either.  So it is filtered out.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=eda81f2548942a42030f7f3cabe9dcb0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer Gordon Linoff. The db fiddle is really a nice touch to your reply ! However, it doesn't reflect the use case I am facing. Using the same wording as you, the difference is not only in number of rows  but also in different `t1.x`. Some values for `t1.x` are just not present when I use the `where` clause, even though they are when I use the `on` condition

Comment: I've edited the question to add an example (I didn't edit the select appropriately, but you'll get the idea

Comment: @mlarcher . . . I adjusted the answer to better fit your data.  If you look at the results without filtering, I think you will see why the rows are filtered out.  There is no `NULL` value because *something* matches.  However, that *something* is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I see that now. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is something you are missing.

`WHERE` and join conditions are only exchangeable for inner joins.

An outer join `a LEFT JOIN b ON ...` is defined as:

- the result of the inner join
- in addition, for every row in `a` that did not find a match that way, we get a result row where the `b` values are replaced with NULL.

So, no matter what the join condition is, the result will always contain at least one row for each value of `a`.

But a `WHERE` condition is evaluated (logically) after the join, so it can exclude rows from `a` from the query result.

Comment: This is the key. An outer join returns the inner join *plus* exactly one instance of any unmatched rows filled out with nulls for the columns on the unmatched side. A simple cross join with a where clause cannot replicate that behaviour - neither the once-only criteria for unmatched rows, nor the null-filling of the columns on the unmatched side.